# maven parent pom does not download dependencies from nexus

Tags: maven, dependencies, nexus

I have setup a nexus and I can deploy my artifacts to my nexus repo. But when i start a mvn compile on my parents pom it does not download the artifacts from my submodules. When i start a mvn compile from a submodule it works ok and it downloads my dependencies from submodules.

so mvn clean compile from parent does not download the ecs-data-contract dependency from nexus but mvn clean compile from ecs-webservice does download the ecs-data-contract dependency.

What am I missing or doing wrong ?

thanks a lot

Here is my parents pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>nl.ict.psa</groupId>
    <artifactId>psa-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>PSA Parent</name>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-public</id>
            <url>http://localhost:9090/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <name>PSA repository</name>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <!-- settings -->
    <properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <commons-lang3-version>3.5</commons-lang3-version>
        <commons-cli-version>1.2</commons-cli-version>
        <log4j-version>2.6.2</log4j-version>
        <junit-version>4.12</junit-version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>ecs-data-contract</module>
        <module>ecs-webservice</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- common dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-lang3-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j-version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-cli-version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Test dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit-version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverId>nexus</serverId>
                        <nexusUrl>http://localhost:9090/repository/psa-public-release/</nexusUrl>
                        <skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

and here is my settings.xml

```
 <settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:9090/repository/maven-public/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>  
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 modules should both be under the same parent, the whole project (parent and 2 children/modules) should build on their own.

Your 2 modules should specify their parent and not set a version or group :

ecs-data-contract pom should look like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>nl.ict.psa</groupId>
    <artifactId>psa-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>ecs-data-contract</artifactId>
```

ecs-webservice pom should look like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>nl.ict.psa</groupId>
    <artifactId>psa-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>ecs-webservice</artifactId>
```

Then when ecs-webservice wants to depend on ecs-data-contract the dependency will look like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>nl.ict.psa</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecs-data-contract</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you are right, i changed that, but that does not solve my problem. The artifacts are still not downloaded when start mvn compile on my parent pom

Comment: I'm not sure what "they" means but ecs-data-contract comes from the project it is not supposed to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the whole `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` plugin configuration from your parent pom.

I have a similar project [bc-framework](https://github.com/bcsoft/bc-framework) with yours. It works fine to download all dependencies when run `mvn compile` within parant project. The difference is I have no `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Very late but I had a similar mistake.

**Solution:** Delete my local .m2/repository folder.

**Explanation:** Corrupted .m2/repository folder

I discovered this solution with this line:

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.repo.local=/tmp/m2
```

Which simulates an **empty or new** .m2/repository folder.

After this, my dependencies started downloading.